# expand a property of a code line which is already executed

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to expand a property of a command that's already been executed?

[image: GUI options]

I'd like to see the whole "Feature Result" Property, but can't access it anymore.

Comment: No, that's why I'm assigning everything to variables in console: `$x = Get-SomeData`. You can than view result later at your pleasure.

Comment: that's what i'm also doing, if i intentionally want to get some information out of a property. in this case I was kind of surprised that there is more than 1 item in "Feature Result". It would be great if there was a functionality that can do this. since the command i executed needs a restart to work his magic, i thought there could be a way to access this property

Comment: That would require some kind of "object" or "pipeline" buffer,  instead of screen buffer. Because what you see on screen was internally written to pipeline, then passed thru formatter and printed to screen. So all internal data is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the Common Parameter `OutVariable` so that you can access the info later.

```
Get-WindowsFeature Server-GUI-Mgmt-Infra -OutVariable WinFtr | Uninstall-WindowsFeature
$WinFtr.'Feature Result'
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. What's the difference between just assigning a variable `$x = get` and the `-outvariable` parameter? Which is the better choice? And is there no chance for me to get my info when I havent assigned a variable or used the parameter?

Comment: The difference is that you can get the output of a command before the end of the pipe. If you just do `$x=` you usually only capture the output of the last command in the pipe. If the data that you want is a part of the output of the last command in the pipe you could then pipe to `|Select -ExpandProperty 'Feature Result'` but then you only see that property and not everything.